# How does one minimize the standard deviation to find optimal parameters?

Tags: regression, python, optimization, standard-deviation, minimum-variance

When doing a generalized least squares fit for a line, one computes the residuals as `(y - (m*x + b))**2`, where `(x,y)` are the observed data points and `(m,b)` are the parameters that optimize the linear fit. Then, one can sum the product of the i-th residual with the i-th weight for all residuals (or weights). The parameters that produce the minimum weighted residual sum are the optimized parameters.

I am told that one can minimize the standard deviation instead of the residuals to find the optimal parameters. As the residuals will consist of multiple data-points (one residual for each `(x,y)`) that can be summed, the standard deviation would consist of a single floating point number that cannot be summed.

I've tried looking online to find more information about minimizing standard deviation, but without success. The closest thing I found [is this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/50277/minimize-the-standard-deviation-of-the-total-values-of-groups-of-items-optimiza), but I don't think this answers my question; also, I am unfamiliar with r, though I do understand python. Can someone please explain the process used to minimize the standard deviation to find optimal parameters?

Comment: I thought SD is independent to regression methods? Are you asking for normalization or data transformation such that the new sample SD is smaller?

Comment: To be perfectly honest, I'm not entirely sure whether or not this falls under normalization or data transformation. My first guess was to take the standard deviation of the observed `y_true` and the standard deviation for each `y_trial = m*x + b` for each `(m,b)` checked in the minimization algorithm such that the square of the difference of standard deviations is minimized, though I don't think/know if this is correct. Any insight into this is welcome, as I am not very well-versed in statistics.

Comment: Standard deviation of what?

Comment: I originally thought it was the standard deviation of trial y = mx + b. But I’m not exactly sure as it I also thought that trial y had to be checked against the observed y. Is minimization of standard deviation/error considered a standard practice for any kinds of statistics?

Answer (score -1):

To minimise standard deviation from what you describe, I think you should fit an intercept only model. A model that always you an constant prediction must have SD of 0.